# Create a new Object with @RequestBody(required=false)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Rest Controller with an optional `@RequestBody` parameter, that I want to initialize if a user does not specify it. Now I'm doing this:

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Page<?>> findAll(
            @RequestBody(required=false) MyRequest request,
            Pageable pageable
        ) {
  if (request == null) {
    request = new MyRequest();
  }
...
}
```

Is there any automatic way to tell Spring MVC that in case the parameter is null it must create a new object?

Comment: I guess it does create a new object and if the request body is empty it doesn't initialize it.

Comment: the thing is that if I do not specifically create a new object like I do, If I try to access an object's method a nullpointer exception pops out

Comment: If there is no request body, then it shouldn't be a `POST` call, why not create a separate `GET` endpoint with same mapping? I think that is the most proper solution.

Comment: I already have one, but I still need to validate this

Answer (score 0):

I don't full control Spring but I think there is not an automatic way to initialize an object like this. If the body is empty, the message converter initializes an object with `null` value. That's why you have a `NPE`. 
You can use the Java 8 `Optional<Myrequest>` even if I've never use it in this case and I'll be curious to know how the message converter treats this case. If you test it, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Remember `@RequestBody` calls the empty constructor of `MyRequest`. Therefore `request` will **always** reference to an instance of that class.

Conclusion: There is no way `request == null` or `request.equals(null)` evaluates to true.